# Cumulative frequency histogram in Pyplot doesn't plot full graph for zero-valued data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a script that I wrote that analyzes data, generates a value (between 0 and 2) for each piece of data, removes some of the data based on an algorithm, then repeats the analysis and generation of values.  At each step of data being removed, it generates a cumulative frequency histogram of the data logs to help visualize the spikes in certain ranges of the generated values with the y-axis going from 0 to 1 (meaning 0% to 100%) and the x-axis going from 0 to 2 (the range of possible values), so that a steep slope in the line graph indicates a large number of values over the particular domain that the steep slope occurs, as in this [frequency histogram example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEdR1.png). (Notice the spikes in the histogram corelate to the slope in the cumulative graph)

The problem I am having is that when I generate my graphs, the cumulative frequency histogram of data that has only zeros generated for its values should be a straight line across the top at `y=1` to indicate 100% of the numbers have a value of zero for that particular plot, but instead I get a line at `y=1` that goes only from `x=0` to `x=0.5` as see in this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmgwj.png). I need the line to go all the way across at `y=1`, from `x=0` to `x=2`.

Here is the code that generates the plots:

```
# Calculate histogram and bins
hist_, bins_ = np.histogram(e.real, bins = 500, normed=0)
cuml = np.cumsum(hist_)
# Plot and normalize data range by dividing values
plt.plot(bins_[:-1], np.divide(cuml,float(max(cuml))) , label=str(rem_) + ' removed', marker = markr.next(), markevery = 9)
# Limit axis ranges to possible values
plt.xlim(0, 2)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
```

The `e.real` is a list object that holds the generated values, here is the value of it that was logged during the plotting of the graph linked above:

```
200 removed
[ 2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.
  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.
  2.  0.  2.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.]
300 removed
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
382 removed
[ 0.]
```

As you can see in the logged values **and** the graph, at *200 removed* the graph visualizes that approximately 80% of the numbers have a value of zero (indicated by the line across `y=0.9` starting at `x=0`) and the rest have a value of 2 (indicated by the plot going from `y=0.9` to `y=1` at `x=2`). In the plots of *300 removed* **and** *382 removed*, the logs show that 100% of the values are zero, and the graph should confirm that with a line across `y=1` starting at `x=0` instead of showing the short line that only goes to `x=0.5` .

(Note: *300 removed* and *382 removed* have the same graph and are overlapped to form the short line; The overlapping is correct behavior)

Any ideas on how fix my line-length? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the  ```300 removed``` data set, specifying a sequence of bin edges instead of the number of bins can make the graph look like you wish.  I didn't try it on the other data sets. Seems like you want the same bin edges for all data sets. ```bins = np.linspace(0,2, 500)``` then
```h, b = np.histogram(data, bins = bins, normed=0)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the range option in np.histogram

```
hist_, bins_ = np.histogram(e.real, bins = 500, range = (0, 2), normed=0)
```